# Can I have html tags in Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

can I have this entry with all these tools such as bold, italic, title, etc:
[I mean s.th like this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah7Il.png)
instead of this:
[default panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv1JS.png)

I've found this solution, but I want s.th better
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxNNw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for WYSIWYG Editor, you can find one here at [Django Packages Website](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/)